# Xcode : cannot change main nib file

Tags: cocoa, xcode, sdk, plist, xib

I have a Home Page .xib and a MainWindow.xib. The plist says MainWindow is the main nib file. I launch the app and all is okay with MainWindow as main/beginning page, but I want to make the Home Page .xib be the main page. I change it in the plist and run my app, and it crashes... Could someone help me please?

Comment: You need to tell us more about the crash if you want a solution. You may even find it yourself while gathering that information.

Comment: Is your target iOS or Mac OS?

Answer (score 2):

It is because your homePage.xib doesn't contain the AppDelegate object and the references off AppDelegate.